# iOS 7 XCode 5.0 IBAction not called

Tags: xib, ios7, xcode5

I have an application developed in iOS4 using XiBs. I got it working all good with iOS6.1 and earlier. But for some buttons, IBAction is not getting called if it is iPhone and iOS 7.0. Also it is working fine with iPad and iOS 7.0. Of course, I am using different Xibs for iPhone and iPad.
Here is the code. It is pretty basic. But just not getting into it.

```
- (IBAction) didReceiveMapButtonPress {
   NSLog(@"IN DID RECEIVE MAP BUTTON PRESS");
   if ([self wasReferredFromMap]) {
    [[self navigationController] popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
   } else {
    [self pushMapViewController];
   }
  }
```

Comment: Please check your linking with button again or past your button code...

Comment: Hi Kokx, Thanks for the reply. I think my linking is all good, because it is working with iOS5.0, 5.1, 6.0 & 6.1.

Comment: Can you post your code for IBAction method? so i will able to understand issue...

Comment: Should't methods linked to an XIB have a parameter `(id)sender`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many of the developer used custom view to show custom cell on Table view for older version of iOS. If you are one of them, then you will have to face a problem that your button click action will no longer work with iOS7.

How to resolve this:

You have three options:

**Option 1**:  Create the new lay out with new table cell instead of taking view. and put all layouts again in table cell.

I know, this will require a lot of effort.If you don't want to do this, we have a very small hack for it:option 2

**Option 2**: Create a IBOutlet for your button and add this button as a subview of your cell's content view.

```
[self.myCell.contentView addSubview:self.btn_click];
```

The above line of code will add btn_click as a subview of you content view. Now button click action should work.

**Option 3:**

**The best way :**

i) Take An outlet UITableViewCell.
ii) Make existing view as subview of new table cell.
iii) Disconnect the connection of custom cell to existing view and connect it to new UITableViewCell.

thats it, Your IBAction will work now.

May be you got the **crash** with error message that **"class is not key value coding - compliant."**. Check your old view connection and remove all connection having yellow mark.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure the TCell.xib for your `UITableViewCell` is correct.

Double check if this xib file has "Content view". If you can not see this item, that means your view is not a `UITableViewCell`, it probably is a `UIView`.

The correct method is to recreate this XIB file. you can do it like this:

1. NewFile(User Interface)--->Empty--->Device Family(iphone)--->Save as TCell.xib.
2. add `UITableViewCell`
3. copy your subview from your previous xib file to this view and connect the outlets. https://i.stack.imgur.com/WB4j3.png

Answer (score 0):

When I faced with this problem, I had tons of cells from xibs. That's way I've create the category for UITableViewCell

```
@implementation UITableViewCell (customs)

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];
    [self reAddSubviews];
}

- (void)reAddSubviews {
    for (UIView * o_vw in [[[self subviews] objectAtIndex:0] subviews]) {
        if (o_vw != self.contentView) {

            [o_vw removeFromSuperview];
            [self.contentView addSubview:o_vw];
        }
    }
}

@end
```